# Graph with treewidth $\Omega(k^2)$ that does not contain a $k \times k$ grid as minor

Tags: graph-theory, trees

In this [book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-319-21275-3), the *Excluded Grid Theorem* by Robertson & Seymour is introduced.

There is one exercise that states the following:

> Show that the dependency on $k$ in the Excluded Grid Theorem needs to be $\Omega(k^2)$.
> That is, show a graph of treewidth $\Omega(k^2)$ that does not contain a $k \times k$ grid as a minor.

I know that a lower bound on the tree width can be determined by the minimum degree of a graph as well as by a minor of the graph.

However, I could not come up with any graph that has a treewidth of $\Omega(k^2)$, but does not contain a $k \times k$ grid as minor. In the book, there is a hint, stating:

> Consider a clique on $k^2 - 1$ vertices.

This confused me even further, as I also know any $k$-clique has a treewidth of $k - 1$ (hence $k^2 - 2$ for the case above).

I guess I either completely misunderstood something or I'm missing something very obvious. I would be incredibly thankful for any approach (further reading material, another hint).

Comment: Well, $k^2-2$ is $\Omega(k^2)$.

Comment: I seem to have issues to understand lower and upper bounds concerning treewidth. I thought a lower bound is the minimum value for a treewidth, hence $k^2-2$ would be an even lower bound than $\Omega(k^2)$. In other words, if the lower bound for a given graph is $k^2$, the treewidth must not be less than $k^2$, but may be more than $k^2$. Any further clarification is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is unrelated to treewidth: a function $f(k)$ is $\Omega(k^2)$ if $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{f(k)}{k^2} > 0$.

Comment: Oh, I was not familiar with that. Thanks!